# Create a new row every n cells in an HTML table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table, presentation

I have the following code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($gallery); $i++)
{
    $temp = array();
    $temp = $gallery[$i];
    echo "<img src='". $temp->path . "' />";
}
```

Now this code prints the content in one row. I want to print only 3  per row and then create new row and print another 3 and so on. How can this be done?

EDIT: error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 5
>
> Filename: views/profile.php
>
> Line Number: 105
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/profile.php
>
> Line Number: 106

Comment: Tables are for tabular data.  An image, by itself, is not tabular data.  If your table had headers, what would they read?  "Image", "Image", "Image"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
$n = 3;
echo "<table><tr>";
for($i=0; $i<count($gallery);$i++){
    $temp = array();
    $temp = $gallery[$i];
    echo "<td><img src='". $temp->path . "' /></td>";
    if($i % $n ==0 && $i!=0 ){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Edit:

If you want to do it the "right" way - by building the syntactically correct HTML, you need to do:

```
$n = 3;
echo "<table><tr>"; 
$gallery_count = count($gallery);
for($i=0; $i<$gallery_count; $i++){
    $temp = array();
    $temp = $gallery[$i];
    echo "<td><img src='". $temp->path . "' /></td>";

    if($i != 0){
        if($i % $n == 0 && $i != $gallery_count-1){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
        else{
            echo ""; //if it is the last in the loop - do not echo
        }
    }
}

//example - if the last 2 `td`s are  missing:
$padding_tds  = $gallery_count % $n;
if($padding_tds != 0 ){
    $k = 0;
    while($k < $padding_tds){
       echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    }
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: This code isn't accounting for the zero at the beginning of the for loop - the first modulus will result in zero - the first line will only have 1 image.

Comment: @Drew - You are absolutely right. I missed that . Just edited the answer

Comment: This is throwing an error...I am using codeigniter and it is showing error edited above in question.

Comment: It's better, but now without the zero starting, it's skipping the first array element for `$gallery[]` - if you're going to do `<=` you should make sure that you're grabbing one index back on the array: `$gallery[$i-1]`

Comment: Last loop loops infinitely

Answer (score 0):

You just need to a `modulus` that checks how many have been printed - any multiple of 3 will add a break.

```
$x=0;
for($i=0; $i<count($gallery);$i++)
{
    $x++;       
    $temp = array();
    $temp = $gallery[$i];
    echo "<img src='". $temp->path . "' />";
    if (($x%3)==0) { echo "<br />"; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just redid it with tables, it's much neater, because each thing will be formatted to look correctly. 
It's kind of messy because I just added a little if statement to release the tables.

```
<table>
<?php
$number_per_row = 3;
for($i=0; $i<count($gallery);$i++)
{
    $temp = array();
    $temp = $gallery[$i];
    if(($i % $number_per_row) == 0) {
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    ?>
<td><?php echo "<img src='". $temp->path . "' />"; ?></td>
<?php
    if(($i % $number_per_row) == $number_per_row - 1) {
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_chunk()` to establish subsets of 3 rows will make the process easier to read and avoid modulus condition mistakes.

To prevent making imbalanced table rows, default an empty value in remaining cells when there is no image path to present.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1A9hZ))

```
$gallery = [
    (object) ['path' => 'imgs/img_a.jpg'],
    (object) ['path' => 'imgs/img_b.png'],
    (object) ['path' => 'imgs/img_c.jpeg'],
    (object) ['path' => 'imgs/img_d.gif'],
];

$template = <<<HTML

    <tr>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
    <tr>
HTML;
echo '<table border="1">';
    foreach (array_chunk($gallery, 3) as $set) {
        printf(
            $template,
            "<img src=\"{$set[0]->path}\">",
            isset($set[1]) ? "<img src=\"{$set[1]->path}\">" : '',
            isset($set[2]) ? "<img src=\"{$set[2]->path}\">" : ''
        );
    }
echo "\n</table>";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$n = 3;
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
for($i=0; $i<count($gallery);$i++){
    if(($i % n ==0) && ($i != 0)){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    $temp = array();
    $temp = $gallery[$i];
    echo "<td><img src='". $temp->path . "' /></td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo '</table>';``
```

Comment: Hi I must have done something wrong because this answer is down voted
but I cudn't find that. Can anyone help me to find out issue in code, or the reason it had been down voted.

Comment: You're missing the `$` for in your `($i % n ==0)` - also, you're not accounting for the fact that the for loop starts on zero - you're first modulus statement will return true because you're comparing against zero ($i's first value) - your second line would have 2 galleries and so on.

Comment: EDIT: Your first line of images would have 4 of them - zero should be counted as a gallery.

Comment: Thanks
your first comment is correct "You're missing the $ for in your ($i % n ==0)"
Though for other, I didn't find issue while running this code.